# Expandable Text in LazyColumn with reverseLayout = true

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have an expandable text in LazyColumn with reverseLayout which expands when I click on `see more`

When I click `see more`, the text expands upwards, so if the text is longer than screen height I'll have to scroll up to read from beginning. I want it to expand downwards, something similar to WhatsApp, where the expansion happens to bottom and the I scroll down to read the text. How can I achieve this?

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Content() {
    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(
            space = 16.dp,
            alignment = Alignment.Top
        ),
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(8.dp),
        reverseLayout = true
    ) {
        items(50) {
            TextMessage(text = text)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun TextMessage(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    text: String,
    minimizedMaxLines: Int = 3
) {
    if (text.isNotEmpty()) {
        var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
        Box(
            modifier = modifier
                .shadow(2.dp, RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
                .background(Color(0xFFCDFFF8))
                .padding(8.dp),
        ) {
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.Bottom
            ) {
                SelectionContainer {
                    Column {
                        Text(
                            text = text,
                            maxLines = if (expanded) Int.MAX_VALUE else minimizedMaxLines,
                            overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
                            onTextLayout = { layoutResult ->
                                expanded = !layoutResult.hasVisualOverflow
                            }
                        )
                        if (!expanded) {
                            Text(
                                text = "See more",
                                modifier = Modifier.clickable {
                                    expanded = true
                                },
                                style = MaterialTheme.typography.labelSmall,
                                color = Color.Green
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```